# Error in updating view on value change using function

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript-angular

I have a list of assignments in my JSON Response which I am using to populate my view using `*ngFor="let assignment of assignmentFeed; let i = index;"`.
Each assignment has a `due_date` property which I pass through a function called `timeRemaining()` to get the time remaining to submit the assignment and show that info in the view. This is what that part looks like in my template:

```
<Label>
  <FormattedString>
    <Span *ngIf="timeRemaining(assignment?.due_date) === 0" class="fab clock-icon" style="color: #f16464;" text="&#xf071;&nbsp;&nbsp;"></Span>
    <Span *ngIf="timeRemaining(assignment?.due_date) !== 0" class="far clock-icon" text="&#xf017;&nbsp;&nbsp;"></Span>
    <Span *ngIf="timeRemaining(assignment?.due_date) === 0" class="remaining" style="color: #f16464;" text="Submission Closed"></Span>
    <Span *ngIf="timeRemaining(assignment?.due_date) !== 0" class="remaining" [text]="timeRemaining(assignment?.due_date)"></Span>
  </FormattedString>
</Label>
```

This is the method that takes the updated deadline and updates the `assignmentFeed` array:

```
updateDeadline(deadline, index){
 const assignment = this.assignmentFeed[index];
 assignment.due_date = deadline;
}
```

The Problem: When the deadline is updated for an assignment, I select the `assignment` in the `assignmentFeed` array using its index and update the due_date value. In the view, however, it shows both the old value and new value for time remaining. For example, if the time remaining was 1 Day 5 Hours and I extend the deadline by 3 hours, the view shows something like **1 Day 5 Hours Remaining 1 Day 8 Hours Remaining**. I should remove **1 Day 5 Hours Remaining** and just show **1 Day 8 Hours Remaining**.

Any help?

Comment: I think this is happening because you are using "const" in updateDeadline function. Try using "let" instead of "const", it should resolve your problem.

Comment: @Xissor Using "let" solved only part of the problem. In cases where timeRemainig() method was already returning a deadline, it works fine but in case where timeRemaining() previously returned 0, the problem still persists. It shows something like, "Submission Closed 1 Day 3 Hour Remaining"

Comment: Try printing the "due_date" using {{assignment[0].due_date}} in HTML file. If the due_Date is updated in HTML and span is showing wrong value, then use changeDetectRef. The second option is assigning due_date as **new Date(deadline)**. If this does not work, please share how you are calling updateDeadline().